# How to merge two arrays of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays of objects:

```js
let employees = [
  { name: 'Jason', job_id: '101' },
  { name: 'Sarah', job_id: '102' },
  { name: 'Jack', job_id: '102' }
]

let jobs = [
  { job_id: '101', position: 'Designer' },
  { job_id: '102', position: 'Developer' }
]
```

Is it possible for me to merge these arrays into one with vanilla javascript, like below:

```js
let employees = [
  { name: 'Jason', job_id: [job_id: '101', position: 'Designer'] },
  { name: 'Sarah', job_id: [job_id: '102', position: 'Developer'] },
  { name: 'Jack', job_id: [job_id: '102', position: 'Developer'] }
]
```

Below is what I have now. It does give me the correct result, however if possible I'd rather not use nested loops.

```
employees.forEach(employee => {
  for (let index = 0; index < jobs.length; index++) {
    if (employee.job_id == jobs[index].job_id) {
      employee.job_id= jobs[index];
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simplest code for array intersection in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript)

Comment: Please share the code you've attempted by adding it to the question as a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task is not very complicated so i will try to make a simple answer with a live demo.

The idea here is to loop through the `employees` array and then construct an object having the structure you want and then push it into a final array.

Each object on the final array will have the following attributes:

- `name`: equal to the name on the `employees` array (on every iteration)
- `job`: to make things clearer, i'd use `job` instead of `job_id` (which you use in your desired result). The `job` is an object containing

  - `id`: the `job_id` from the `employees` array
  - `position`: the respective position from the `jobs` array.

To have the above result, we will use the `reduce` method wich will construct the final array along the way.

The other task is to get the respective `position`, from the `jobs` array, based on the `job_id` from the employees table. To do so, we'll use the `find` method wich will return the first match it finds on the `jobs` array.

With that being said, let's have a live demo (the demo has some useful comments):

```js
const employees = [{
      name: 'Jason',
      job_id: '101'
    },
    {
      name: 'Sarah',
      job_id: '102'
    },
    {
      name: 'Jack',
      job_id: '102'
    }
  ],
  jobs = [{
      job_id: '101',
      position: 'Designer'
    },
    {
      job_id: '102',
      position: 'Developer'
    }
  ],
  /** 
   * "res" is the resulting array after performing the needed operations 
   * "reduce" method loops through the "employees" array and populates the "res" array along the way
   */
  res = employees.reduce((a, c) => {
    /**
     * a: the accumulator, it holds the last value from the previous iteration. Initially it equals to an empty array "[]" (see 3rd argument passed to the "reduce" method)
     * c: is the current element from the "employees" array on each iteration
     */

    /** adds an object that follows the intended structure to the final array */
    a.push({
      name: c.name,
      job: {
        id: c.job_id,
        /** 
         * find the respective "position" based on the "job_id" of the current element of element of the "employees" arrray 
         * el: holds the element from "jobs" array on each iteration of the "find" method
         * the condition is once we find an elemnt having "job_id" equals to the current element (i mean "c" parameter) "job_id" then return that object's "position" attribute
         * once we found the "position" we simply save it on the object we're constructing
         */
        position: jobs.find(el => el.job_id == c.job_id).position
      }
    });
    /** return the array so that the next iteration of "reduce" can do its work */
    return a;
  }, []);

/** print the result */
console.log(res);
```

> The above demo is *definitely* not the only way to have things done, surely there are some fancy `ES6` ways to do that especially when it comes to constructing the objects. For the sake of simplicity, i wouldn't use those fancy/complicated tricks to keep things as simple and understandable as possible.

> Learn more about the [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method on MDN.

> Learn more about the [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method on MDN.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for the detailed comments. Now to worry about performance as it's quite a large json I am working with, but that's for later. Thanks again.

Comment: @Liam Thank you! Glad I managed to help. For the performance, you could have a dictionary object that holds the `psotion`s so that once you find a `position` you could simply get it for the next time using `myDictionnarty[c.job_id] // return the positon of that job_id` (am improvising here) and you wouldn't need to lop over and over again.

Comment: Yes that was my first thought as soon as I posted the question, great to have that validated! Cheers.